OAuth2 Redirecting to Wrong URL After Authentication in NGINX with auth_request
I’m trying to use OAuth2 to authenticate users on my server, but after successful authentication, they are being redirected to the base domain instead of the intended sub-path, /example/. I’ve determined that the redirection target should be injected into the headers using add_header $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for, but the auth_request /oauth2/auth directive is stripping all custom headers, including this one. Despite multiple attempts to preserve the headers, they are removed during the authentication process. How can I ensure the headers remain intact through OAuth2 so users are properly redirected to the correct sub-path after authentication? I've been searching the web and trying everything for 2 days on this
    location /example {
    # Perform OAuth2 authentication
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;

    # If the user is authenticated, attempt to preserve headers
    auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_user;

    # Debugging headers - we’ve tried setting them for troubleshooting
    add_header X-Debug-User $user always;
    add_header X-Debug-Redirect $upstream_http_x_auth_request_redirect always;

    # Also tried sending the headers without the body
    auth_request_set $auth_redirect $upstream_http_x_auth_request_redirect;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;  # This was used to pass only the headers
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";  # No content length since body is removed

    # Attempted to add headers after authentication for custom redirection
    proxy_set_header X-User $user;
    proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $auth_redirect;

    # Forward to the internal service after authentication
    proxy_pass https://localhost:6521/;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /oauth2/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4180;  # OAuth2 Proxy port
    proxy_pass_request_body off;  # Pass only headers
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";  # No content length since body is removed
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    client_id= "12345678901234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    client_secret= "abcde-abcdefghijklomn"
    provider = "google"
    redirect_url = "https://mydns/oauth2/callback"
    pass_access_token = true
    pass_host_header = true
    pass_authorization_header = true
    set_xauthrequest = true

    cookie_secret = "1235467890abcdefghijkl"
    cookie_secure = true
    authenticated_emails_file = "/etc/oauth2_proxy/authorized_emails.txt"

    upstreams = ["https://192.168.0.10:6521/"]

I feel like I've exhausted every option on this as far as changing my config file around and making minor changes.  Are there any troubleshooting things I should try?  Is it possible there is something wrong with docker containers or anything like that?
